# Как на JavaScript или jQuery сделать появление элемента в таблице, которая генерируется на PHP?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть таблица, состоящая из трех столбцов ("Номер", "Название" и пустой столбец).
Она генерируется с помощью PHP (выводит данные из БД в шаблон).

Как сделать, чтобы при наведении на ряд в таблице, в пустом столбце этого ряда появлялась кнопка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну например так

```js
   $(".myTable tr:not(:nth-child(1))").hover(
  function() {
$(this).find('td:last-child').append('<button class="myButton">My Button</button>');
  },
  function() {
$('.myButton').remove();
  }
);

$("body").on("click", $('.myButton'), function() {

  alert("button click");
})
```

```css
.myTable {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 30px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.myTable td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.myButton {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  color: #000;
  background-color: pink;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: ponter;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>номер</td>
    <td>название</td>
    <td>пустой столбец</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Text1</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Text2</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо, а как сделать, чтобы кнопка появлялась, при наведении мышки на ряд, т.е. на любую ячейку? И не появлялась в заголовке таблицы?

Comment: Исправил, ответ